# How can i execute a css3 transition when the document loads using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

i was just wondering if i could make a form slide when the page loads

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/gi.css">

 </head>
 <body onload='document.getElementById("form1").style["-webkit-transform"] = "translateX(100px);"'>
 <form action='gi.php' method='post' id='form1'>
 <!-- form elements -->
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

that's the code im working on

note: this html will be placed inside an iframe

any responses would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this

```css
form {
  transform: translateX(1000px);
  -webkit-animation: move 2s forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes move {
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0)
  }
}
```

```html
<form action='gi.php' method='post' id='form1'>
  <input type="button" value="button">
  <input type="button" value="button">
  <input type="button" value="button">
  <input type="button" value="button">
  <input type="button" value="button">
  <input type="button" value="button">
</form>
```

Comment: thanks Akshay for the answer


will that code run when the page loads ??

Comment: @YesSir Yes you can try the snippet

Comment: Hey dude thanks i just tried the code you gave it works fine ^-^ thanks.